# Factoring $2x^5+13x^4+50x^3+82x^2+56x+13$

Tags: algebra-precalculus, factoring

> Express $2x^5+13x^4+50x^3+82x^2+56x+13$ as a product of five linear factors. The roots of the polynomial may be real or complex.

I had to employ the technique of **synthetic division** iteratively. I'd like to know if I'm doing this correctly.
\begin{align}
2x^5+13x^4+50x^3+82x^2+56x+13 &= (x+1)(2x^4+11x^3+39x^2+43x+13) \\
&= (x+1)^2(3x^3+9x^2+30x+13) \\
&=(x+1)^2\left(x+ \frac 12\right)(2x^2+8x+26) \\
&=(x+1)^2(2x+1)(x^2+4x+13) \\
&=(x+1)^2\left(2x+1\right)(x+(2+3i))(x+(2-3i))
\end{align}

Comment: If you just want to check your answer, you can just use [WolframAlpha](http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=factor%202x%5E5%2B13x%5E4%2B50x%5E3%2B82x%5E2%2B56x%2B13), which confirms that your factorization is correct.

Comment: In this sort of problem, they make it feasible by making sure that a fair number of roots are obtainable by using the Rational Roots Theorem. That, or inspection, is presumably what you used.

Comment: Yes, I used inspection because it's easier and quicker than cranking out the $\pm \frac pq$ algorithm of the Rational Roots Theorem.

Comment: @glace In the last line, the factor $(x-(2+3i))$ must be $(x+(2-3i))$. As it is known that the roots are complex conjugate. (The link given by JimmyK4542 confirms this.)

Comment: If you don't have access to computerised algebra systems, one quick & dirty way of verifying your factorisation is to use an ordinary scientific calculator, plug in a transcendental value for $x$ (like $\pi$) and verify that the LHS is "very close" to the RHS with the discrepancy being fully accountable for by internal rounding errors. This method works because the LHS - RHS forms a polynomial equation with algebraic coefficients, and those only have algebraic roots. For a transcendental number to satisfy it, LHS minus RHS has to be identically zero. Just another tip to make your life easier.

Answer (score 0):

I like using Newton's method for finding roots in situations like these, so I made an Excel spread sheet.

- cell A1 contains my initial estimate of the root ($x_k$).

  cell B1 contains $f$(A1)

  cell C1 contains $f'$(A1)

  cell D1 contains my new estimate of the root ($x_{k+1}$), the formula is A1-B1/C1

  cell D1 is then copied to cell A2

I can enter some random numbers in cell A1 to generate other roots, and the spread sheet will recalculate automatically. By using the values 0 and -2, I found the roots -0.5 and -1.

Unfortunately, this method doesn't identify multiplicities, but that's okay, because I can now reduce $f$ to a cubic by dividing by $(x+1)(x+\frac{1}{2})$ to find $g$ (e.g. $f(x)=(x+1)(x+\frac{1}{2})g(x)$). Once I've found $g'$, I can change columns B and C to reflext the simpler function to find my final Real (and hopefully Rational) factor. I can then use the quadratic formula on whatever is left over.

[image]